# Running Upstart user jobs on startup

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I am running Ubuntu server 11.04. I have created an Upstart user job as described [here](http://bradleyayers.blogspot.com/2011/10/upstart-user-jobs-on-ubuntu-1110.html).

I have the following file at my `/home/myuser/.init/sensors.conf`:

```
start on started mysql
stop on stopping mysql


chdir /home/myuser/mydir/project
exec /home/myuser/mydir/env/bin/python /home/myuser/mydir/project/manage.py sensors

respawn

respawn limit 10 90
```

As `myuser` I can start, stop, and reload the job fine- it works perfectly:

```
$ start sensors
sensors start/running, process 1332
$ stop sensors
sensors stop/waiting
```

The problem is that the job is not starting automatically at boot when `mysql` starts. After a fresh boot, `mysql` is running but my `sensors` job is not.

What's strange, is that although the job doesn't begin on bootup, if I use `sudo` to restart `mysql` it does indeed start my job. The following commands are run as `myuser` from a fresh startup:

```
$ status sensors
sensors stop/waiting
$ sudo restart mysql
mysql start/running, process 1209
$ status sensors
sensors start/running, process 1229
```

The documentation for Upstart user jobs is pretty limited. What is the correct technique to have a user job start automatically on startup of the system?

I know I can just throw something in `rc.local` to start it, or I could move my `sensors.conf` to `/etc/init` but I'm curious if there is a way to do it using just Upstart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that user jobs aren't loaded into Upstart until the user creates an Upstart session by running one of the `initctl` commands.

I've described it in more detail at http://bradleyayers.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/enabling-upstart-user-jobs-to-start-at.html and also written an Upstart job that works around the problem.

Comment: There's another way to do this documented at http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#non-graphical-sessions-ubuntu-specific — it has a bug though, you'll need to change "start session_init" to "start session-init".

Answer (score -1):

Looking at sources like `/etc/init/mysql.conf` and http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-on it seems to me you should change your `start on` line to something like this:

```
start on (mysql and runlevel [2345])
```

I'm not sure I agree that upstart lacks documentation, but I sure do have a tough time understanding the docs sometimes. I usually just do trial and error until its working. The solution above may be overkill actually... something as simple as this may be sufficient:

```
start on mysql
```

Comment: It's not that upstart lacks documentation in general, it's that it doesn't have much documentation regarding user jobs- jobs placed in /home/$USER/.init (not jobs placed in /etc/init).

Comment: I tried your suggestions but no difference. It's not a problem with my `start on` line, but it's just the fact that upstart only loads /etc/init on startup, but not user init files in their `$HOME/.init`

Comment: Sorry, missed that this was a user job and not a job in `/etc/init`. You are correct that documentation appears to be lacking for that and I'm not sure how to ensure `~/.init` scripts are started.

Comment: The docs I could find indicate the `$HOME/.init` jobs are not enabled by default and some changes to `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/Upstart.conf` might be required. http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user